# Enlarged partition, filesystem still reports old size

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

I resized the root partition with GParted, from 20 GB to 40 GB, but the filesystem still reports a size of 20 GB.

How can I use all 40 GB?

---

**Update**

The resized partition was an LVM Physical Volume (/dev/sda2), and the boot partition is ext4 (/dev/sda1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the common case of an ext2/3/4 filesystem, the answer would be `resize2fs`, part of the `e2fsprogs` package. It can even run on mounted partitions.

#### Usage:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda3
```

where `/dev/sda3` is the partition you want to resize. This automatically expands the filesystem to occupy the whole partition.

### Update

In your case, with LVM, there are additional steps necessary:

1. Resize the Physical Volume with `pvresize /dev/sda2`
2. Look at either `mount`, `/etc/fstab` or `vgdisplay` or `lvdisplay` to get your root filesystems volume name. It should be something like `/dev/MyVolumeGroup/MyRootVolume`.
3. Add the free space to your volume with the following command: `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/MyVolumeGroup/MyRootVolume`.
4. Then, resize the filesystem: `resize2fs /dev/MyVolumeGroup/MyRootVolume`

After this procedure, you should be able to utilize the newly added space.

Comment: After I use this command I got the error:
"Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock."

Comment: So did you specify the correct partition? Are you even using an ext filesystem? You can check both by running `mount`.

Comment: Of course, the partition I resized to 40GB is /dev/sda2 on my machine. It has lvm2 pv in its "File system" info.

Comment: I see, so you’re using LVM and `/dev/sda2` is not your root partition but a LVM Physical Volume. I’ll update the answer later.

Comment: @TheKolanN I’ve updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The LV will now be 100G, but the overlying filesystem will still be 90G.

LVM utils like lvs, lvdisplay etc. will show 100G

System utils like df, du etc. will show 90G.

Resizing the filesystem will depend on which filesystem you’re using and where it’s mounted.

Assume the LV is mounted at /space

Some common standard filesystems are ext4 and xfs.

If you’re using xfs:

**xfs_growfs /dev/sda3**

If you’re using ext4:

**resize2fs /dev/sda3**

Comment: Where do those numbers come from?